# Работа с *.STL файлами в С++

Tags: c++, 3d

Подскажите пожалуйста, какую технологию выбрать для работы с *.STL файлами, и если возможно, небольшое интро в нее. Мне нужно считывание и обработка 3d координат для решения мат. задачи (нахождение пути через площадь).

Answer (score 1):

На [CyberForum.ru](http://CyberForum.ru) вам уже дали ссылку на один репозиторий.

https://github.com/dillonhuff/stl_parser/blob/master/parse_stl.cpp

Здесь основной код парсера STL-файлов. Разбирайте, копипастите в свой проект.